# Matlab: assigning values to variable in for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

So I have 10 matrix, they are 20x20 size. Here, I want to store the first row of the first matrix and store onto the variable call f_row1, then the first of of the second matrix to f_row2......

So A1, A2..... A10 is my 20x20 matrix.

```
f_row1=A1(:,1);

f_row2=A2(:,1);  %and so on.....
```

Is it possible for me to do it in a loop? How could I do this process in a loop?

Comment: Don't do this. You shouldn't be storing data that you're going to use together in separate variables. Your `A1, A2... A10` arrays should be `A(1,:,:), A(2,:,:)... A(10,:,:)`. Then your problem is trivial. As it stands there is no good solution.

Comment: Beaker, because I am reading the files from the excel, which has 10 sheets. I need to extract thoses row vectors and give them meaningful names.

Comment: You can specify the sheet and which submatrix to put the data into like `A(7,:,:)=xlsread(filename,7)` instead of using `A7`.

Comment: @kuku did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As @beaker said, there may not be a *good* solution. You can use `eval` to achieve what you want as follows:

```
for i=1:10
 eval(['f_row' num2str(i) '=A' num2str(i) '(:,1);']);
end
```

I haven't tested it but should work.